# How to initialize Racket libraries, environment at org-mode buffer startup

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

As the title says, I want a number of things to happen when I open an org-mode file: I want a Racket REPL session to start (as in a code block `:session mysess1`) and I want various Racket environment-library things to happen, e.g., initialize `(require math)`. I've thought about Emacs local file variables, but not sure how it can first start a particular named REPL session, then run the `(require math)`. There is also the org mode tag `#+STARTUP`, but again I'm not sure how that would happen. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make a named src block that sets up the racket env you want.

Then, use a local variable to go to that block and execute it. Maybe something like this:;

```
#+name: setup
#+BEGIN_SRC racket :session mysess1
(require math)
#+END_SRC


# Local Variables:
# eval: (progn (org-babel-goto-named-src-block "setup") (org-babel-execute-src-block))
# End:
```

You will probably get pestered with getting asked to evaluate the local variable when you open the file, but I think this will do what you want.

Comment: BTW, what is your org-mode racket setup?

Comment: Org mode version 9.0.2; Racket v6.7; Geiser 20161202.1657.

Comment: Actually, I just got a `File local-variables error: (error No org-babel-execute function for racket!)`

Comment: That makes sense. There isn't an ob-racket that I know of.

Comment: I am trying to setup https://github.com/hasu/emacs-ob-racket/, but, honestly, I have not yet got it working

Comment: In fact, this other project works, at least for basic evaluations: https://github.com/wallyqs/ob-racket